# Custom Autocomplete With Ajax/jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm creating custom autocomplete with help of Ajax, jQuery and I have hard-coded one database which is created in PHP as I am getting correct output. But when I click on any text in the autocomplete box it does not get selected.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#search_Textbox").keyup(function () {
        var searchbox_Value = $("#search_Textbox").val();
        $("#serach_Result").show();
        if ($("#search_Textbox").val() == null || ($("#search_Textbox").val() == "")) {
            $("#serach_Result").hide();
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: "custom_database.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                text_Value: searchbox_Value
            },
            success: function (server_Response) {
                $("#serach_Result").html(server_Response);
            }
        });
    });

    $('a').bind('click', function () {
        alert("yes");
        var achor_tag_text = $(this).val();
        alert(achor_tag_text);

        $("#search_Textbox").text(achor_tag_text);
    });
});
```

Comment: that is different than only display :)

Comment: actully problem is at the last I am not getting alert in that $("a").bind so please could you help me??

Comment: Why don't you try $('#id').on('click','a',function(){
//perform action here
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `.on()` function it is more preferable from **jquery 1.7**

```
$(document).on('click','a', function() {
       alert("yes");
       //do your stuff
       var achor_tag_text = $(this).val();
       alert(achor_tag_text);
       $("#search_Textbox").text(achor_tag_text);
});
```

but don't bind common element to click event give an class name to an element then bind your event with that class

Comment: when i click on text in autocomplete does not get selected, as i am trying to create like google suggestion

Comment: if you have your selected text inside `<a>` tag then you can get value by `$(this).text();` not  like this `$(this).val()` .val() used to get value from only form elements like `<input>,<select>`

Comment: Deep Kakkar,Anwar Hussain,Musa,Dezza thank you all its working.

Answer (score 1):

You are binding to the `<a>` tags which are present at the initial load of the page, not those that are present when the ajax returns.

Change your `$('a').bind('click', function() {` to `$(document).on('click', 'a', function() {`.

Comment: ok thanx, I am getting alert now but could when i click on text in autocomplete does not get selected like when google suggestion if you want i would like to show you my php database page

Comment: try changing `$("#search_Textbox").text(achor_tag_text);` to `$("#search_Textbox").val(achor_tag_text);`. I assume here that `#search_Textbox` is an input field.

Comment: when i run this i'm not getting any values. As I tried to check wheather alert(achor_tag_text);  giving some value or not. And the result is nothing showing it.

Comment: Try also changing `var achor_tag_text = $(this).val();` to `var achor_tag_text = $(this).text();` - `val()` is only used for form fields.